# How to partition hard drive in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I'm literally brand-new to Linux and Ubuntu, so please forgive my ignorance and bear with me here. I purchased a Dell Inspiron 5593 recently and immediately installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it. Long story short, the keyboard is screwed up, and the place I bought it from won't service Linux OS. Gotta be Windows/Mac OSX for some stupid reason.

So now I'm trying to partition the hard drive and reinstall Windows on the the partition. I've checked out [GParted](https://gparted.org/), but I haven't been able to follow the documentation. For example, I don't see any unallocated space on my disk, and I'm not willing to unmount my main disk without knowing what that will do to my computer.

Honestly at this point I'm ripping my hair out and would just appreciate some clear instructions on how to partition a hard drive in Ubuntu 20.04 because I'm clearly too technically illiterate to understand GParted's documentation.

Comment: You should not need to run GParted at all. The Windows installer does the re-partitioning for you, whether you want it to or not. Simply back up your data, then boot the Windows installer. It will do the rest.

Comment: It sounds like you removed Windows when you installed Ubuntu. In that case, it's best to wipe the disk, reinstall Windows **first**, and then install Ubuntu using the "Install Ubuntu along side of Windows" option. This will create a dual-boot environment, and you'll still be able to get support from the Windows-support only folks, and Ubuntu support here. See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/index.html for more help.

Comment: Could also make new question explaining why keyboard is screwed up.  Unless it is broken hardware problem, someone here might help.  Gparted should be used from another drive like you ubuntu USB installer.

Comment: @crip659 Different keys on the keyboard are  intermittently not working and repeating. It very much seems to be a hardware issue. Since it's a brand new machine (less than a month old), and I've done every BIOS and driver check I could find, the only thing left is hardware.

Comment: If you don't have a Windows installer USB yet, Download the same version of windows you had, and also install 'woeUSB or mkUSB' to make a Windows USB that can boot and install windows, don't worry about partitions let windows do it.  Take back computer for repair/replacement.